# Group_by or similar in Haystack-django-solr

Tags: solr, django-haystack

I have indexed 1 million comments at solr with haystack in the 'text' field. Othewise, I have a restaurantId at the same Index, which belongs to the restaurant, the one that has been made the comment. And I'd like to look for comments group by restaurantId. Is something like group_by in haystack?

I have this query to look for comments with some words:

```
query_set = SearchQuerySet().using('comments').raw_search('text:nice\ fast\ clean')
```

If there is something like:

```
query_set = SearchQuerySet().using('comments').group_by('restaurantId').raw_search('text:nice\ fast\ clean')
```

Cheers! And thanks in advance!

**Update 1**

Now I want to add this experimental code: https://gist.github.com/acdha/3750774#file-solr_grouping_backend-py to my project.

How could I do it? Where I have to paste that code?

Comment: grouping is not yet supported in haystack.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Thanks for your comment, any alternatives to group_by?

Comment: you can try faceting as an alternative to it..

Comment: here i got a link for you could you check if it could be helpful https://gist.github.com/acdha/3750774

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try this!